# Arithmetic progression. find in terms of n

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Find in terms of n: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} 2r-1$$ and  $$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}  3r+3 $$

I tried using summation but they said in terms of n and then  I expanded substituting from numbers 1 and 4.

Comment: Are we deemed to read over your shoulder ?

Comment: I entered an image but where is it?

Comment: so sorry I fixed it

Comment: Do you recognize a known summation formula ?

Comment: I advise you to have a look  on http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference  in order to have a more organized and clear question.

Comment: no summation formula

Comment: @TeshaCaesar yes in the link there is no summation formula, but a MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference for you in order to ask a well organized and clear question.

Comment: Okay, the problems are visible. Where did you get stuck? What have you tried so far? Is there a concept you would like to understand better?

Comment: for the first question I choose r to be numbers from 1 to 4 up to n but for the second question I don't know how to attempt that

Comment: well I just stopped up to there then said...2n-1

Comment: Okay , why you choose $4$, the formula is summing up to n?? 
Hint: for the first one you may write  $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} 2r+1= 2 \Bigg( \sum_{r=1}^{n}r  \Bigg) +1$$ . Now check  this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF     it may help you.  You can proceed with the second one in the same way.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: If you have solved your problem please consider accepting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, lets use $$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}  3r+3 $$

as an example. I am going to break the two sums up into $$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}  3r+\sum_{r=0}^{n}3 $$ and notice that the term being summed over in the second sum does not change, it is simply $3+3+3+...+3$ added $n$ times.

That gives us $$3n+ \sum_{r=0}^{n}  3r $$

Focusing on $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}  3r $$

I'll pull out the $3$ leaving us with  $$3\sum_{r=0}^{n}  r $$

I am not sure if you have seen this but $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}  r = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

There is an explanation here: http://www.csun.edu/~ac53971/pump/20081014_basic.pdf

So, all totaled you have $$3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+3n$$

But this can be used to solve any problem like that. For $$ \sum_{r=0}^{n}  ar+b $$ you have $$a\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+bn$$